# UPDATE transaction crashes using sqlite3 python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to update values in sqlite3 database file. I run the following code:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

con = sqlite3.connect(r'test.db')
sql = con.cursor()

general = pd.DataFrame(columns=['isin', 'issued_volume', 'amt_out', 'res_nominal_value', 'next_offer_date', 'offer_price', 'option_type'])
general.loc[len(general)] = ['test_isin', 200000, 200000, 500, np.nan, 100, 'put']
general.to_sql(name='general', con=con, index=False)

flds = ('issued_volume', 'amt_out', 'res_nominal_value', 'next_offer_date', 'offer_price', 'option_type')
update_values = (200000, 200000, 1000, '10.02.2022', 100, 'call', 'test_isin')
sql.execute(f"""UPDATE general SET {flds} = (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  WHERE isin = (?);""", update_values)
con.commit()
```

But the OperationalError occurs:

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ca5d6f2301b7> in <module>()
      1 flds = ('issued_volume', 'amt_out', 'res_nominal_value', 'next_offer_date', 'offer_price', 'option_type')
      2 update_values = (200000, 200000, 1000, '10.02.2022', 100, 'call', 'test_isin')
----> 3 sql.execute(f"""UPDATE general SET {flds} = (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  WHERE isin = (?);""", update_values)
      4 con.commit()

OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

What am I doing wrong?

For the note, this code works flawlessly on another machine. So I figure the difference in outputs might be in library versions. I made sure the sqlite3 library was the same, but copying the folder "sqlite3" to the Anaconda3 -> Lib directory. I am running the code in Jupiter notebook.

Comment: `SET` clauses must consist of column / value pairs, like `SET col1 = 'A', col2 = 'B'...`.  Not `SET col1, col2 = 'A', 'B'`.

Comment: You must be using a SQLite version at or before 3.14.2 to generate that error with that SQL statement.  You'll need to pull in a version of SQLite newer than 6 years old to fix this.